# Codeigniter | Calling Stored Procedure with IN and OUT pratameters in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, call, procedure

This is my procedure... it's going to accept a parameter of `$encoder` as IN and then it will output the number of members as `@current`, `@cancelled` and `@year` it was encoded as OUT. I got one IN parameter ans four OUT parameters... and it works.

The problem is how am i going to do this in Codeigniter 3.

I've tried several codes refering to the codeigniter manual but i got this error..

```
Error Number: 1172

Result consisted of more than one row

CALL get_members_by_status(25,@current,@current,@year1)

Filename: models/Dashboardcounts.php

Line Number: 189
```

This is the Mysql Procedure code..

```
BEGIN
    -- current members
     SELECT
                count(memstat) INTO current
            FROM
                members
            WHERE
                encoder = encoder_num
                    AND memstat = '1';

     -- canceled members
     SELECT
                  count(memstat) INTO cancelled
            FROM
                members
            WHERE
                encoder = encoder_num
                    AND memstat = '0';

    -- year encoded
     SELECT
                  date_format(memdateencode,"%Y") INTO year1
            FROM
                members
            WHERE
                encoder = encoder_num;
    END
```

This is my Model Code...

```
public function linegraphchurchmemberbychurch_2(){
        $query = $this->db->query('CALL get_members_by_status(25,@current,@current,@year1)');
        $query1 = $this->db->query('SELECT @current');
        foreach ($query1->result_array() as $row){
        $data = $row;
        }
         return $data;
        }
```

Any hint?

Comment: Are you sure that none of your `SELECT...INTO...` return more than one row ?

Comment: I did try the procedure in mysql console and it works...i just can't  make through codeigniter